# Comparing which set better represents data

Tags: self-study, standardization

Here's the question/assignment:

> Twenty football players practised goal shooting, each had 6 attempts. Here's the per-player score results:
>   $$ \begin{array} {|r|r|} \hline 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3  & 3 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 6 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\ \hline \end{array} $$
>   **a)** Make a *frequency table* (proper terminology might've been lost in my translation)
>   **b)** Calculate $M_o$ (Mod) and explain the meaning of it.
>   **c)** On the second training the average goals was $ 3.7 $, with a standard deviation of $ 0.8 $. For which training does the mean ($\overline{x}$) better represent the set?

My question is mostly about **c**, but I'll put my solutions for **a** and **b**, too in case they help with explaining **c**.

My friend wrote on the margins next to **c** "standardizing", but I am not sure if they're related. Which is actually why this confuses me so much! I *haven't got the slightest idea* on how to apply satandization here.

I'd have just calculated the standard deviation ($\sigma$) for both sets and decide the one with the smaller standard deviation more accurately represents the set, because the values are more "*densely*" together.

---

**EDIT** I don't need *the* actual solution (although I don't mind if it helps in explaining), a small guide on how to get to it would suffice.

---

### a) *Frequency table*

$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
x_i & f_i & f_i x_i & f_i(x_i - \overline{x})^2 & N_i \\
\hline
1 & 3 & 3 & 16.5675 & 3 \\ 
\hline
2 & 5 & 10 & 9.1125 & 8 \\
\hline
3 & 3 & 9 & 0.3675 & 11 \\
\hline
4 & 3 & 12 & 1.2675 & 14 \\
\hline
5 & 3 & 15 & 8.1675 & 17 \\
\hline
6 & 3 & 18 & 21.0675 & 20 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

(Seems you can't do Markdown tables, so I resorted to a $\LaTeX$ array)

### b) Mod

This one is easy(<del>I think</del>). It's just the $x_i$ from the row with the largest $f_i$: $$ M_o = 2 $$

### c) Which set is a better representation of the team's skill?

#### First Set

$$
\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{f_ix_i}}{N} = \frac{67}{20} = 3.35
$$

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}{f_i(x_i-\overline{x})^2}}{N}} = \sqrt{\frac{56.55}{20}} = 1.725
$$

#### Second Set

$ \overline{x} = 3.7 $
$ \sigma = 0.8 $